# insert multiple rows based on an if condition

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am returning an array of results which I put into a foreach loop and each result checks against a single amount. As long as the condition is met it should insert rows. However, no data is ever inserted into the database but the error logs are also empty ie: I get no errors.

```
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
           if ($invoice->amount <= $this->amount) {
               $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `payment_link` (`amount`) VALUES (:amount)");
               $stmt->bindValue(":amount", $invoice->amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $stmt->execute();
           }
        }
```

`print_r($invoices)` gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => App\Models\Invoice Object ( [customer_id] => [description] => [date_created] => [amount] => 300.00 [total:App\Models\Invoice:private] => [invoice_id] => [line_description] => [line_amount] => [errors] => Array ( ) ) [1] => App\Models\Invoice Object ( [customer_id] => [description] => [date_created] => [amount] => 500.00 [total:App\Models\Invoice:private] => [invoice_id] => [line_description] => [line_amount] => [errors] => Array ( ) ) ) Array ( [0] => App\Models\Invoice Object ( [customer_id] => [description] => [date_created] => [amount] => 300.00 [total:App\Models\Invoice:private] => [invoice_id] => [line_description] => [line_amount] => [errors] => Array ( ) ) [1] => App\Models\Invoice Object ( [customer_id] => [description] => [date_created] => [amount] => 500.00 [total:App\Models\Invoice:private] => [invoice_id] => [line_description] => [line_amount] => [errors] => Array ( ) ) )
```

Comment: check this `if ($invoice->amount <= $this->amount) {` condition, if its `TRUE`, second check `print_r($invoices)` what r u getting and share the result.

Comment: Thank you. I `$this->amount` is 800 and `$invoice->amount` are 300 and 500. If I echo out $invoice->amount then I get 300 and 500 so it is true. Will post the `print_r` in my original question now..

Comment: replace `VALUES (:amount)` with `VALUES (?)` and try.

Comment: That gives me Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Comment: Replace `$stmt->bindValue(":amount", $invoice->amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);` with `$stmt->bind_param("s", $invoice->amount); `

Comment: @executable That's mysqli syntax, OP is using PDO.

Comment: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()'

Comment: Right before your if, try `echo "$invoice->amount <= $this->amount<br>";` to see if it's going to hit the if statement. Inside your if, after your execute, add `"echo "Should have run execute<br />"`. See what lines pop up

Comment: Can you please try with `$stmt->bindParam('?', $invoice->amount);` or `$stmt->bindParam(':amount', $invoice->amount);`

Comment: @aynber: condition is true

Comment: @aynber, I get: 300.00 <= 800
Should have run execute
500.00 <= 800
Should have run execute

Comment: @devpro Yes, but a little more troubleshooting to verify never hurts.

Comment: i am not expert but may be it happened due to property `$invoice->amount`

Comment: @devpro, keep getting this error with the ?: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Comment: Try checking for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) before and after your execute to see if anything pops up. If you have access to the database server and logs, you can always try turning on `set global general_log = 1` before the query, and `set global general_log =0` after the query, then check the mysql log to see what shows up.

Comment: @aynber, I have this already. Is it sufficient? `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: one last suggestion: `if ($invoice->amount <= $this->amount) {` after this line put this line `$amount = $invoice->amount;`

Comment: @devpro, could you please post an answer with full code because I am getting lost here with all the different code snippets and don't know which ones of yours to use/not use

Comment: follow comments one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on the code in the question and not discussion in the comments]

You need to get eyes-on; have the computer tell you why it hasn't inserted any rows. From the [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php): `$stmt->execute();` *Returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure.* .

Test the result and post it to the error log (or echo to screen, whatever works for you).

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result) {
    error_log("row inserted successfully");
} 
else {
    error_log("insert FAILED");
}
```

If there is *no* feedback, the loop didn't execute or one of the previous statements failed. (They also return TRUE on success and FALSE on failure).

If it says "insert FAILED", you can get more detailed information from [PDOStatement::errorinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php).

If it says "rows inserted successfully", well then there is something to investigate. (For example: does program use TRANSACTIONS and needs a commit?)

Start with gathering the information you don't have, it will help you track down the real problem.